# Who was the old dog in the space suit?

Tags: plot-explanation, shaun-the-sheep

In Space Bitzer, the fourth episode of Shaun the Sheep: Adventures from Mossy Bottom, there is an old dog in a (presumably?) Soviet space suit. This old dog meets Bitzer, who is dragged to space by a drone, and takes a selfie with him.

Who is that dog? Is it older Bitzer himself? Or is it someone else? What happened?

Comment: Without watching the movie - most likely [Laika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laika), the dog that was sent to space by USSR.

Comment: @Yasskier that was my first idea, too. But I think there must be a reason why the dog looks like very old Bitzer (some relativity effect near a black hole, maybe?)

Comment: The ending references "2001: A Space Odyssey" (as the music clearly indicated)..